# First django_project / password reset timeout error

Tags: django, passwords, timeout, reset, errno

I'm following an incredibly informative tutorial series on YouTube by a guy named CoreyMS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&t=394s

I've made it the 12th video where he is teaching me how to set up a password reset page. I initially had trouble getting my gmail info placed in an environment variable, and perhaps that is still my problem, but every time I type in my email then hit Request Password Reset it just does nothing for a long time then eventually times out:

> /password-reset [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Comment: Consider adding some code so we can better help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having that problem try to follow the "Python Quick Tip: Hiding Passwords and Secret Keys in Environment Variables by Corey Schafer" where he told to close the editor after setting the values of EMAIL_USER and EMAIL_PASS in settings.py file to save that and open the editor again and make sure your EMAIL_PORT is 587 which is the default E-mail port.

Just follow the steps carefully to solve it. Happy Coding :)